# Angular - Find a given value in an array within another array

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an angular app, where I need to check security groups on a machine (array of security_groups).
I have a function that receives the serverId and checks array of machine details in the security groups attached on the server, that security group is an array of object. I tried to do this but with a map function, but I'm not getting it.

When I go to request a console.log (serverDetails), only a single object returns to me, and not an array of objects, where I should have all objects from all servers, can you help me?

My code:

```
export class MachinesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {

  public selectedServer: any;
  public selectedMachine: any;
  public flavors: any[] = [];
  public machines: any[] = [];
  public serverDetails: any[] = [];
  private alive: boolean = true;
  public form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private serverService: MachineService, 
    private openstackService: OpenStackService,
    private modalService: NgbModal, 
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      flavorRef: new FormControl('')
    })

    forkJoin(this.serverService.getServer(), 
    this.appService.getFlavors())
    .pipe(takeWhile(() => this.alive))
    .subscribe((data) => {
      this.machines = data[0];
      this.flavors = data[1];
      this.machines.map((item) => {
        this.serverService.getServerById(item.id)
        .pipe(takeWhile(() => this.alive))
        .subscribe((data: any) => this.serverDetails = data)
      })
    })
    this.setExpanded();

  }



findSelectedMachineDetails(serverId): any {
    return this.serverDetails.map((item) => {
      if(item.id === serverId.id) {
        return item['security_groups'].map(item => item.name)
      }
    })
  }
```

My Html:

```
<tbody>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let machine of machines">
          <tr >
            <td (click)="machine.expanded = !machine.expanded">
              <div class="user-info">
                <div class="user-info__img">
                  <img src="./assets/img/cloud4.svg" alt="Usuário Img">
                </div>
                <div class="user-info__basic">
                  <h5 class="mb-0">{{machine.name}}</h5>
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td (click)="machine.expanded = !machine.expanded">
              <span class="active-circle bg-success"></span> Status
            </td>
            <td (click)="machine.expanded = !machine.expanded">{{machine?.flavor?.disk}} GB</td>
            <td (click)="machine.expanded = !machine.expanded">{{machine?.flavor?.ram}} GB</td>
            <td>[{{findSelectedMachineDetails(machine)}}]</td>
            <td (click)="machine.expanded = !machine.expanded">{{machine?.flavor?.vcpus}}x 2.8Mbps</td>
          </ng-container>
        </tbody>
```

My response GET serversById

```
[
  {
    "name": "hello",
    "id": "1879f47f-1c5e-464b-bb76-e7cc13ef426e",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "hostId": "30f3f23f5668cf5ae13f0951fb8364063c43dc5be40f9df202a97fe8",
    "flavor": {
      "id": "21f46a72-7f4f-40c5-9f1f-0100fadbc226",
      "disk": "10",
      "ram": "4000",
      "swap": "",
      "vcpus": "4"
    },
    "security_groups": [
      {
        "name": "default"
      },
      {
        "name": "test"
      },
      {
        "name": "again"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "hell3",
    "id": "1879f47f-1c5e-464b-bb76-e7c313ef426e",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "hostId": "30f3f2343668cf5ae13f0951fb8364063c43dc5be40f9df202a97fe8",
    "flavor": {
      "id": "21f46a72-7f4f-40c5-9f1f-0100fadbc226",
      "disk": "10",
      "ram": "4000",
      "swap": "",
      "vcpus": "4"
    },
    "security_groups": [
      {
        "name": "default"
      },
      {
        "name": "test"
      },
      {
        "name": "again"
      }
    ]
  },{
    "name": "hell2",
    "id": "1879f47f-1c5e-464b-bb76-e7c213ef426e",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "hostId": "30f3f23f5668cf5ae13f0951fb8364063c43dc5be40f9df202a97fe8",
    "flavor": {
      "id": "21f46a72-7f4f-40c5-9f1f-0100fadbc226",
      "disk": "10",
      "ram": "4000",
      "swap": "",
      "vcpus": "4"
    },
    "security_groups": [
      {
        "name": "default"
      },
      {
        "name": "test"
      },
      {
        "name": "again"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this piece of code. From quick glance it looks like you're rewriting the array instead of pushing to it:

```
  this.machines.map((item) => {
    this.serverService.getServerById(item.id)
    .pipe(takeWhile(() => this.alive))
    .subscribe((data: any) => this.serverDetails.push(data)) 
    //serverDetails is initialized with empty array so it should work
  })
```

**EDIT:**

Problem is that you are mixing synchronous code with asynchronous code and this is prone to cause such strange issues.

Let's consider the code below. When the `machines` are rendered in `ngFor` cycle `serverDetails` are most likely not initialized yet (so the array is either empty or incomplete) and since it's a synchronous code, it is not notified of the updates that to `serverDetails` happen bit later.

```
<td 
 *ngFor="let secGroup of findSelectedMachineDetails(machine)"
>
  ....
</td>
```

I don't see the whole code of yours I would suggest some changes and only display data, when everything is indeed finished.

```
forkJoin(
  this.serverService.getServer(), 
  this.appService.getFlavors()
)
.pipe(
  takeWhile(() => this.alive),
)
.subscribe(([machines, flavors]) => {
  this.flavors = flavors;
  this.machines = machines.map((item) => ({
    ...item, // spreads the object -> makes copy of it
    securityGroups: this.serverService.getServerById(item.id)
    .pipe(map(server => server["security_groups"])) 
    // do not subscribe to this, async pipe will take care of it
  }))
})
```

This will get you the data you want and then processes the machines array where for every machine it adds another property to the object - `securityGroups`. This is an async property, where it expects the result from `getServerById()` call.

Then just adjust the HTML and it should work. I haven't compiled the code and did some assumptions so be sure to check it and maybe adjust some mappings.

```
 <td *ngFor="let secGroup o machine.securityGroups | async">
  {{secGroup.name}}
 </td>
```

Comment: Hello, this really works, but I am not understanding the behavior in my HTML. When ngfor happens, some machines have only 1 object array with a security group, others have 2,3,4, so it spreads empty values ​​in my HTML, could you help me? Image of the problem attached to the question. I adjusted my code too.

Comment: html image link with ngfor result: https://imgur.com/x5UP6Ml

Comment: Wow. This is incredible, I don't think about using a spread operator, I didn't know it very well, I'm relatively new/noob in programming. Is there a way to put the values ​​in a single td of the table? since ngfor will generate a column for each value ... I thought about using an ng-template but there would have to be a trigger for that, and I would not like to create a trigger.

Comment: Yes you can, just move the `ngFor` one level down `<td><span *ngFor="let secGroup o machine.securityGroups | async">{{secGroup.name}}</span></td>`